# Start procedure from when it stops

Tags: sql, database, oracle, procedure

I have a long procedure that I want to save the state. This is for starting from when it stops if something in the database happended. 
How can I implement it in Oracle?

Comment: Save the state in a database table?

Comment: But i want the procedure to start somewhere in the code, something like a startpoint. Is it posible?

Comment: There is nothing built-in to do this, you would need to devise your own solution.

Comment: If your stopping point is deterministic, then you can conditionally start the pl/sql block execution. If it is abstract as you mentioned `something in the database happened`, it will be a lot of condition matching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved the problem. Thanks to comments I realized that it's not posible to put some start poin in procedure.

I've created an aux table `ProcState` where I saved the state of the procedure. 
When I start the procedure, through a Query I loop in registers that I've not inserted in `ProcState`

When the procedure runs, I insert and commit the validations that I dont want to check againg if the DBMS breaks.

Finally, when procedure ends I delete all registers in `ProcState`for starting from 0 the next time.

Hope It helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with your own solution.

I advice you with this solution:

Put `if case` front of every `dml statements` and check it s ok or not.

I mean You can put `1` end of every `dml statements` and check it before your run that block. It is long way I know but it solve your problem.